# Flutter and Facebook SDK Errors

Tags: flutter, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to implement Flutter Version 3.3.7 to Facebook SDK Version 33. we are getting errors, is there any solution for this. Complete Android App and IOS APP is not working, its throwing errors. please share me the solutions as soon as possible.

Thank You..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.